# Creating a view SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

These are the tables I have to work with.

customer (**cust_id**, name, city, postcode)

order (**order_id**, cust_id, date)

orderline (**order_id, video_id**, quantity)

video (**video_id**, description, price, category_id)

category (**category_id**, description)

I need to:

Create a view named CustomerSummary which shows the customer name along with the total number of videos ordered and total order value for each customer.

Comment: What've u tried so far? At least, show your effort....

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createview.html

Comment: do you have any auto increment columns?

Comment: `order` is a reserved word. Don't use it as an identifier, even if it appears to work.

Answer (score 1):

you have to join three tables for required output as below -

```
    SELECT c.Cust_Id,
         c.NAME,
         COUNT(DISTINCT o.Order_Id) Num_Of_Order,
         COUNT(*) Num_Of_Video
    FROM Customer c, Order_Table o, Orderline Ol
   WHERE c.Cust_Id = o.Cust_Id
     AND o.Order_Id = Ol.Order_Id
   GROUP BY c.Cust_Id, c.NAME
```

now for this query you need to create view -
Just add `Create or Replace View CustomerSummary as` before this query to create view with name **CustomerSummary**